# Conditional Multiplication and Cumulative sum

Tags: algorithm

Recently I came across a coding question and I wanted to find the algorithm for it.

```
Array is 1-based array.
Query types: 
1 L R X K : Multiply from L to R with K if it is less than X
2 L R: Print the sum from L to R

INPUT:
6 5
5 4 3 2 6 1
Q1: 1 2 3 5 4
Q2: 2 1 2
Q3: 1 1 3 4 5 
Q4: 2 3 4
Q5: 2 4 5

OUTPUT:
21
14
8

Explantion:
Q1: 5 16 12 2 6 1
Q2: Print 21(5+16)
Q3: 5 16 12 2 6 1
Q4: Print 14 (12+2)
Q5: Print 8 (2+6)
```

Generally here each query takes O(n) complexity to solve. But the algorithm should solve it in even less time.How can I do that?

Comment: After some taught first line 6,5 is number of elements in array and number of queries, and queries are `type,L,R,X,K` and `type,L,R` you should clarify that in text as most of us when see such discrepancies just pass this question and or close vote ... Still where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only improvement I can think of right now (without knowing anything about input data properties) is using cumulative sums.

So have an array `s[n]` that stores the sum of the input data `a[n]` ...

```
s[i] = a[0] + a[1] + ... + a[i]
```

So computing sum of range `l<=r` is done like this in `O(1)`:

```
sum(l,r) = s[r] - s[l-1]
```

That will speed up your type 2 query from `O(n)` to `O(1)`. However the type 1 queries will be slowed a bit as you need to maintain the sum array. The complexity will not change however so they will be still `O(n)` and the final complexity would be `O(m.n)`

**Here example of naive and improved version in C++:**

```cpp
const int eod=-1;                   // end of data
int a[]={ 5,4,3,2,6,1,eod };        // data
int q[]=                            // queries
    {
    1,2,3,5,4,
    2,1,2,
    1,1,3,4,5,
    2,3,4,
    2,4,5,
    eod
    };
const int n=(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))-1;

int i,j,y;
int l,r,x,k;
mm_log->Lines->Add("[naive]");
for (i=0;;)
    {
         if (q[i]==1)   // O(n)
        {       i++;
        l=q[i]-1; i++;
        r=q[i]-1; i++;
        x=q[i]; i++;
        k=q[i]; i++;
        if (l>r){ j=l; l=r; r=j; }
        for (y=0,j=l;j<=r;j++)
         if (a[j]<x) a[j]*=k;
        }
    else if (q[i]==2)   // O(n)
        {       i++;
        l=q[i]-1; i++;
        r=q[i]-1; i++;
        if (l>r){ j=l; l=r; r=j; }
        for (y=0,j=l;j<=r;j++) y+=a[j];
        mm_log->Lines->Add(y);
        }
    else break;
    }

mm_log->Lines->Add("[cumulative sum]");
int s[n];
for (y=0,j=0;j<n;j++){ y+=a[j]; s[j]=y; }   // init cumulative sum
for (i=0;;)
    {
         if (q[i]==1)   // O(n)
        {       i++;
        l=q[i]-1; i++;
        r=q[i]-1; i++;
        x=q[i]; i++;
        k=q[i]; i++;
        if (l>r){ j=l; l=r; r=j; }
        for (y=0,j=l;j<=r;j++)
         if (a[j]<x) a[j]*=k;
        // update cumulative sum
        j=0; y=0; if (l) y=s[l-1];
        for (j=l;j<n;j++){ y+=a[j]; s[j]=y; }
        }
    else if (q[i]==2)   // O(1)
        {       i++;
        l=q[i]-1; i++;
        r=q[i]-1; i++;
        if (l>r){ j=l; l=r; r=j; }
        // use cumulative sum
        y=s[r]; if (l) y-=s[l-1];
        mm_log->Lines->Add(y);
        }
    else break;
    }
```

just change the `mm_log->Lines->Add()` to any print function you got at your disposal.

**Here output:**

```
[naive]
21
14
8
[cumulative sum]
21
14
8
```

Another improvement would be to check for `max(l,r)` of type 2 queries which is `O(m)` so you can ignore/cut of unneeded elements of `a[n]` and `s[n]` speeding up the update process of type 1 queries not counting above the max index. Here updated code for this:

```cpp
mm_log->Lines->Add("[cumulative sum]");
int s[n],sn;
for (i=0,sn=-1;;)           // check for max index in output ranges O(m)
    {
         if (q[i]==1) i+=5; // O(1)
    else if (q[i]==2)       // O(1)
        {       i++;
        l=q[i]-1; i++;
        r=q[i]-1; i++;
        if (l>r){ j=l; l=r; r=j; }
        if (sn<r) sn=r;
        }
    else break;
    } sn++;
for (y=0,j=0;j<sn;j++){ y+=a[j]; s[j]=y; }  // init cumulative sum O(sn)
for (i=0;;) // O(m.sn)
    {
         if (q[i]==1)   // O(sn)
        {       i++;
        l=q[i]-1; i++;
        r=q[i]-1; i++;
        x=q[i]; i++;
        k=q[i]; i++;
        if (l>r){ j=l; l=r; r=j; }
        if (r>=sn) r=sn-1; 
        for (y=0,j=l;j<=r;j++)
         if (a[j]<x) a[j]*=k;
        // update cumulative sum
        j=0; y=0; if (l) y=s[l-1];
        for (j=l;j<sn;j++){ y+=a[j]; s[j]=y; }
        }
    else if (q[i]==2)   // O(1)
        {       i++;
        l=q[i]-1; i++;
        r=q[i]-1; i++;
        if (l>r){ j=l; l=r; r=j; }
        // use cumulative sum
        y=s[r]; if (l) y-=s[l-1];
        mm_log->Lines->Add(y);
        }
    else break;
    }
```

Resulting in complexity `O(m.sn)` where `sn<=n`. If you store `sn` for each type 2 query then you can handle it as variable speeding up the stuff even more.

In the complexities `n` is number of elements in input array `a[]` and `m` is number of queries.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)